# I m working on Rich link preview which showing error while after input and LeonardoCardoso its not working also

Tags: java, android, xml

i have try this code:rich link preview by ponam kartik:

```
          if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(txt_send.getText().toString())){
               Toast.makeText(MessagingActivity.this, "Valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

richView.setLink(txt_send.getText().toString(), new ViewListener() {
                    @Override

public void onSuccess(boolean status) {
                        linkreveal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

```
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                }
            });
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(MessagingActivity.this, "Not Valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```